# Jupyter Notebook Bigquery export result (all rows not just the 15 visible rows) into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I'm a newbie with Jupyter.

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run some GCP BigQuery queries, and I want to save into a CSV the output of those queries (regardless of display row limit).

Only all I can find is about adding the query to a pandas dataframe and then export, but when I try to add the query to a pandas dataframe it throws an error.

Code:

```
`import pandas as pd

data = {%%bigquery
SELECT
*
FROM `wig-eu-aig-prod`.AGGR_CRN_aig.crn_aig_wig_mon_1month_aggr
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)`
```

Error:

```
File "/tmp/ipykernel_29883/1883432173.py", line 3
    data = {%%bigquery
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I remove the %% but I still get syntax error but this time pointing at the * on line 5.

I think I'm not doing this correctly at all...but I've been googling what to do most of the morning and I still haven't got a clue

Answer (score 0):

This may solve the problem:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "/home/user/12345.json")
bqclient = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

query_string = """YOUR_QUERY_HERE"""

dataframe = (
    bqclient.query(query_string)
    .result()
    .to_dataframe(
        create_bqstorage_client=True,
    )
)

dataframe.to_csv("your_csv.csv",sep=',',index=False,columns=dataframe.columns)
```

Go to IAM / Service Accounts and generate the key.json file to add as credentials.

Comment: I haven't got direct access to GCP or Google big query I don't think I can access the IAM/Service accounts. All I can do is querying the data through Jupyter Notebook. I can create the query and I get an output with 15 visible rows (out of 50 thousand) what I want is to extract what I have queried into a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong:

%%bigquery is a magic command. Check this:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter#query_notebook_data_using_the_bigquery_magic_command

```
import pandas as pd
```

```
%%bigquery data

SELECT
  *
FROM 
 `wig-eu-aig-prod.AGGR_CRN_aig.crn_aig_wig_mon_1month_aggr`
```

```
data.head()
```